# Export function with promise, wait for response

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I'm calling a function inside a `then` statement, and that function has to wait for an event to fire, but my initial function is returning `undefined` almost immediately:

```
// call.js
const dialogflow = require('./dialogflow')
module.exports = {
  receive: functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    ...
    let respondToUser = getUserId
      .then((uid) => {
        payload.uid = uid
        dialogflow.handleIncoming(payload).then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
        })
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        response.end()
      })
    ...
  }
}

// dialogflow.js
module.exports = {
  handleIncoming: (payload) => {
    ...
    let df = dialogflow.textRequest(message.message, {
      sessionId: payload.from
    })
    .on('response', (response) => {
      return response.result.fulfillment.speech
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      return 'That\'s an error on my end. Try again later!'
    })
    .end()
  }
}
```

The goal is to call `dialogflow.handleIncoming(payload)` from `call.js`, wait for it to return some text, and then continue. But no matter how I have structured it, `receive` just keeps blowing through it and `dialogflow.handleIncoming(payload)` ends up `undefined`.

I've tried using a promise on `df` with no success, and I can't figure out how to make `respondToUser` wait for a full response from `handleIncoming`. Everything else is working so I'm only including relevant code.

This is using api.ai (dialogflow), but in cloud functions in Firebase if that helps. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `dialogflow.handleIncoming(payload)` is not structured for async. Try this:

```
// dialogflow.js
exports.handleIncoming = (payload) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    let df = dialogflow.textRequest(message.message, {
      sessionId: payload.from
    })
    .on('response', (response) => {
      resolve(response.result.fulfillment.speech)
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      reject ('That\'s an error on my end. Try again later!')
    })
    .end()
  }
```

Comment: This sent me down the right path. Thanks! I had to set handleIncoming to return the new Promise and then return dialogflow.handleIncoming(). Unless that's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your receive function isn't waiting for `dialogflow.handleIncoming(payload)` to complete.  The `then` function that contains it doesn't have a return statement, so it's returning `undefined` rather than returning the result of `dialogflow.handleIncoming` (which is what you want).

```
let respondToUser = getUserId
      .then((uid) => {
        payload.uid = uid
        return dialogflow.handleIncoming(payload)
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        response.end()
      })
```

The next `then` statement will contain the response from `diagflow.handleIncoming`.